# Shorthand for toggling variable between 2 non-boolean values

Tags: javascript

I really like the new JS syntax for swapping variables

```
[a, b] = [b, a]
```

and I was wondering if there's a similarly elegant solution to 'toggling' a value between one of 2 states, when the states aren't boolean:

```
long.complicated.object.reference[index] = long.complicated.object.reference[index] === 'v1' ? 'v2' : 'v1'
```

I know it could be shortened using a temporary variable

```
var cv = long.complicated.object.reference[index]
long.complicated.object.reference[index] = cv === 'v1' ? 'v2' : 'v1'
```

But that still seems long-winded, and *was* the solution to the variable swapping problem before destructuring...

Comment: The "shorthand" is defining an function on `long.complicated.object` which does this for you.

Comment: Why don't use bool if you just have two values. Like `long.complicated.object.reference.isV1 = !long.complicated.object.reference.isV1` ? There's no way for javascript to know that you only have two values, and what they are if you don't tell it somewhere yourself.

Comment: I agree with @meagar that this functionality probably belongs on `object` - additionally, if you're referencing something that deep on your object structure directly, it may be indicative that the overall structure may need refactoring somewhat - see the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: In the real app, the object in question is a deeply nested reference to the result of a firebase query, so adding functions to it or refactoring isn't trivial. It's a string which can take one of 2 values, and these need to be toggled before being written back to firebase

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for the states.

```js
var states = { foo: -2, '-2': 'foo' };
    state = 'foo';

console.log(state);
state = states[state];
console.log(state);
state = states[state];
console.log(state);
```

Comment: See my comment above - the objects are part of a firebase result, so I'm not sure exactly how to apply this answer in the scenario I gave above?

Comment: i do not understand the real problem, you could give the toggle part to a function with an object, the key and a value.

Comment: That's true - but likewise you could also write a function `swap(a, b)` which would swap two variables round. Or you could write `[a, b] = [b, a]`.

Comment: but the question is, do you have a toggle problem or an access problem with nested properties?

Comment: I have a code length problem :). I suspect the answer is that the temp variable is the shortest / most elegant way currently, until `a ~= 'v1' : 'v2'` becomes a thing.

Comment: yes, use temp. `a ~= 'v1' : 'v2' ` has syntax error.